# signals and slots qt close slot

Tags: qt, qt-signals, slot

I made a window and a button in it. I want the button to close the window when clicked, BUT I want to do it by a public slot that I created and which contains the close slot of the `QWidget`, instead of doing it using the default `QWidget::close()`. Here is my code.

window.h

```
#ifndef FENETRE_H
#define FENETRE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

class fenetre: public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    fenetre();

public slots:
    void another();

private:
    QPushButton *button1;
};

#endif // FENETRE_H
```

window.cpp

```
#include "fenetre.h"

fenetre::fenetre():QWidget()
{
    setFixedSize(300,300);
    button1=new QPushButton("click",this);

    connect(button1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(another()));
}

void fenetre::another()
{
    fenetre().close();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "fenetre.h"

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    fenetre fen;
    fen.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: In your implementation of `another` you have `fenetre().close()`.  That will create a temporary `fenetre`, call `close` on it and then go out of scope.  Change that line to simply `close()`.

Comment: thanks it works now !!

Comment: That's what you get for naming your classes with lowercase names... When you see `Fenetre()` it at least should raise an eyebrow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the code in the slot: `fenetre().close();`. Here `fenetre()` creates a new object on which `close()` is called. So simply call `close()` in the slot and all should work as you expect.

Also consider to use the Qt5 style connect with function pointers since they are more secure in general and dont require you to tag functions with "slots" in the header file:

```
connect(button1, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &fenetre::another);
```